# How to sum same id and value from the second column across different csv files and save results into a new csv with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 3 csv files that contain IDs and activeUsers columns. The IDs in those files are sometimes present in only one file, two files but sometimes they can be present in every file. My IDs are unique in each file.

**each csv file format:**

```
      id                activeUsers
470c-9930-4495c5             4
     ...                    ...
```

I need to build a logic in pandas that will help me obtain the following:

- Out of 3 files if ID is in each of them and sum of activeUsers from
  all files = 0 then mark TRUE
- Out of 3 files if ID is present in less than 3 files OR if sum of
  activeUsers from all files is greater than 0 then mark FALSE

**desired results in a new dataframe:**

```
     id           IDoccurenceInFiles       SumOfActiveUsers    True/False
470c-9930-4495c5           2                        4             FALSE
123a-8870-1234a3           3                        0             TRUE
```

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

#3 monthly files
df1 = pd.read_csv('09-2020.csv', sep = ',')
df2 = pd.read_csv('10-2020.csv', sep = ',')
df3 = pd.read_csv('11-2020.csv', sep = ',')

#rename columns in each file
df1.columns = ['id','activeUsers']
df2.columns = ['id','activeUsers']
df3.columns = ['id','activeUsers']

#create dataframe to capture results
df4=pd.DataFrame()

#calculate 'IDoccurenceInFiles' to see if a particular ID would be present 1, 2 or 3 times
df4['IDoccurenceInFiles']=df3.groupby('id')['id'].map(df2['id'].value_counts(),df1['id'].value_counts())

#calculate 'SumOfActiveUsers' across 3 files
df4['SumOfActiveUsers']=

#calculate 'True/False' based on the logic listed above
df4['True/False']=

df4.to_csv('results.csv', index = False)
```

For my first calculation (IDoccurenceInFiles) I received the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Probably I'm trying to overcomplicate this for myself. Could someone help please. thank you in advance.

Comment: Are duplicated `activeUsers` in some file?

Comment: Each file has unique IDs, but IDs can be repetitive across the files, and have same number of activeUsers in each file if this is what you asked.

Comment: Yop, then solution working well. (I hope so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not duplicated `activeUsers` in some file you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for join together with aggregate by counts and sum and last set new column by conditions:

```
df4 = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
         .groupby('id', sort=False)
         .agg(IDoccurenceInFiles = ('activeUsers','size'),
              SumOfActiveUsers = ('activeUsers','sum'))
       )
df4['True/False'] = df4['SumOfActiveUsers'].eq(0) & df4['IDoccurenceInFiles'].eq(3)

df4.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Comment: I just checked and it looks like I was able to save a results file, however there is an issue with the `TRUE` results. If there are 3 IDs occurrences across my files it should only mark last column as `TRUE` if `SumOfActiveUsers` column `== 0`. See here https://imgur.com/a/Vl8evhX Would you be able to help with this? Also, I can't see id column saved in results file, is this because it's not in between brackets where we have  `.agg` ?thank you for your help with this!

Comment: @Baobab1988 - Do you think AND or OD between masks? If AND use `df4['True/False'] = df4['SumOfActiveUsers'].eq(0) & df4['IDoccurenceInFiles'].eq(3)` `Id` is index, so you can omit `index=False` for write it to file.

Comment: It worked after replacing | with & and removing index=False. Thanks a million @jezrael!